# Navigator's popN is not a function?

Tags: react-native

When I try to use Navigator's popN, the error message is:

ExceptionsManager.js:76 Unhandled JS Exception: this._navigator.popN is not a function.

It is OK if I call Navigator's pop function.

Why?

Comment: What platform and React Native versions are you using? popN was introduced to iOS in RN 0.32.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Are you sure popN only works for iOS? The Document has not mentioned it.

Comment: No, it should work on both. I was asking what platform and RN versions you are using so that we can rule out some of the options.

Comment: did  you solve the issue ?